# Using Timer class properly

Tags: c#, coding-style, timer

I would like to know if the code I wrote is a properly written one, it does function, but I've done bad designs before, so I need to know if I thought this in a proper way.

Code is about using a System.Timers.Timer to do a repeated action each X hours. I read some threads about this subject on stackoverflow and then I tried writing my own class. Here is what I wrote:

```
namespace MyTool
{
public  class UpdaterTimer : Timer
{
    private static UpdaterTimer _timer;
    protected UpdaterTimer()
    { }

    public static UpdaterTimer GetTimer()
    {
        if (_timer == null)
            _timer = new UpdaterTimer();

        SetTimer(_timer);
        return _timer;
    }

    private static void SetTimer(UpdaterTimer _timer)
    {
        _timer.AutoReset = true;
        _timer.Interval = Utils.TimeBetweenChecksInMiliseconds;
        _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed);
        _timer.Start();
        DoStuff();
    }

    static void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        DoStuff();
    }

    private static void DoStuff()
    {
       //does stuff on each elapsed event occurrence
    }
}
}
```

Short description:

- tried using a singleton pattern since I only need one timer to work
- I'm not sure about calling DoStuff() inside the SetTimer() method, it seems redundant. But the logic is that, when the app starts, DoStuff() must run, and then it must run again on each Timer.Elapsed event.

My questions are:

1. Would you have written this behavior in a different way, given the specification?
2. Is it ok to use a singleton in this case, or it doesn't make sense?

Comment: "to do a repeated action each X hours" that *so* sounds like a scheduled task to me...

Comment: @Tocco thank you for your comment, will remove it from there in this case.

Comment: @Andrei, Errr ... I was wrong, `DoStuff()` will not be called on `Start()`. Sorry ...  =/

Comment: @Marc Gravell - I am concerned about your comment, you mean Timer should not be used at all for scheduled tasks? could you explain why?;  @Tocco - no problem

Comment: @Andrei no, I don't mean "not at all"; but something on that interval *might* be easier to schedule as a scheduled task. You don't have to - I'm not forcing you to. I'm just suggesting it to ensure you have considered all the available options.

Comment: actually I did not know I could use another approach for scheduling tasks. Thank you for making me aware of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve but here is a few point about your current design:

1. Your `GetTimer` is broken in multithreading mode:

   `if (_timer == null)
       _timer = new UpdaterTimer();`

   suppose you have two threads each one call `GetTimer` at the same time, the first one checks the _timer and found it null so it proceed. but at that time and before it reach `_timer = new UpdateTimer()` the thread context switching switch to the other thread and pause the current thread execution. so the other thread check the `_timer` and find it not null so it proceed and create a new timer, now the context switch rescheduled the first thread and its continue its execution and so create a new timer and update the old one. to correct use of singleton pattern use static constructor instead `static UpdaterTimer() { _timer = new UpdaterTimer();}`
2. The developer can call `GetTimer()` as much as he wanted so it will call `_timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed);` again registering another `Elapsed` handler. Also note that whenever you call `GetTimer`, the timer will start "`_timer.Start()`" even if it were stopped.
3. Don't return the underlying timer, instead expose a public methods `Start()`, `Stop()`, `UpdateInterval(int interval)`.
4. At `SetTimer()` you want to call `DoStuff` immediately, but that then will be blocked at the `SetTimer` method waiting `DoStuff()` to complete, a better way is to start that method in a new thread `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback((_) => DoStuff()));` or use [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) instead of `System.Timers.Timer` and set it call the method start immediately.

Answer (score 4):

I'd venture that making a subclass of Timer is of very little utility. You've turned about 7 lines of code into a whole load of bloat. Given that your `DoStuff` method is private, this isn't going to be reusable in any way. As such, consider the following few lines:

```
Action doStuff=()=>{
    //does stuff on each elapsed event occurance
};
_timer=new System.Timers.Timer(){
    AutoReset = true,
    Interval = Utils.TimeBetweenChecksInMiliseconds
};
_timer.Elapsed += (s,e)=>doStuff();
_timer.Start();
doStuff();
```

where `_timer` is a property of the containing class. The intent here is clear. I don't think it deserves a class of its own.

### Edit:

```
(s,e)=>doStuff()
```

is a lambda expression that defines a delegate that takes two parameters `s` and `e` (sender and event). As this is added to `_timer.Elapsed` event (of type `ElapsedEventHandler`), the compiler can infer the types `s` and `e` from the event type `ElapsedEventHandler`. The only action that our delegate performs is `doStuff()`.

In longhand, this could be expanded to:

```
_timer.Elapsed += delegate(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e){doStuff();};
```

The lambda allows us to write the above considerably more succinctly.

Comment: I'd remove the last line `doStuff();`

Comment: Faithful to original design. Perhaps OP wants an immediate invocation prior to waiting for 1st timer tick?

Comment: thank you very much; as this is my 1st task of this kind, with timed actions, your comment is allowing me to learn; however I cant understand this line, could you please explain it: _timer.Elapsed += (s,e)=>doStuff();

Comment: @Andrei : I added some info for you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use composition here instead of inheritance. (i.e. do not inherit from Timer, just use a Timer as a private field)
Also if code outside of you class shouldn't change timer's properties, you shouldn't show it to other classes. If you want to give an ability to outer code to subscribe to timer's `Elapsed` event, you can add an event for it and trigger it in your `DoStuff` handler, if not -- just hide it.

**code expample as requested by OP in comments:**
NOTE: It **doesn't** match specification (it's a whole different usecase, for your usecase you do not need a separate class after all (refer to another answer)) but shows how can you use composition and hide implementation details. (Also the example has some thread-safety issues but that's not the point.)

```
public static class TimerHelper
{
    private static Timer _timer;

    static TimerHelper()
    {
        _timer = new Timer(){AutoReset=true, Interval=1000};
        _timer.Start();
    }

    public static event ElapsedEventHandler Elapsed
    {
        add { _timer.Elapsed += value; } 
        remove { _timer.Elapsed -= value; }
    }
}
```

And to use:

```
// somewhere else in code
TimerHelper.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(TimerHelper_Elapsed);
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment; I inherited from Timer so that the UpdateTimer object would have the properties of a Timer. I could not call _timer.Start() so I figured I should inherit Timer. Also, could you please provide a short pseudocode, so I can understand how to "hide" the timer. Sorry for missing what may be obvious.

Comment: @Andrei, "hide" means that you declare that fields as private and do not expose (return) its value by any public method or property. Or expose it's individual members. You clearly do not need to inherit from timer because you don't override or add to its behaviour. After some thought, I think I agree with @spender. You just need to create a timer as a field in your application or main window class and do not define a separate class. Still I'll update answer with some code.